# Page not performing well in IE (possible problem with AJAX Control Toolkit Comboboxes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ajaxcontroltoolkit

First of all hello!

I have some problems regarding page performance (mostly load times) in Internet Explorer. The only AJAX Control Toolkit control I'm using on a web page is combobox with autocomplete that is being binded on a page load.

I thought the problem was in large amount of data binded to the comboboxes (from 3000-5000 records), but I got surprised when I checked the page in Firefox and Opera loading times were high, but still acceptable (15 seconds max for the large form) (which can be seen on IMG 1) and almost instant for the small form (which can be seen on IMG 2).

**IMG 1**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PdJz.png

**IMG 2**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql9Ms.png

Is there a way to somehow optimize page for IE (and even more for other browsers if possible). I don't think the code is needed because I'm using simple LINQ queries just to bind data to comboboxes on page load (binding on a page load is a must). I've also tried by setting the web.config debug="false", but I wasn't able to see any differences at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that a JavaScript-based dynamic "combo box" with it's data sent down as a JSON object in a script will drastically outperform any modification/replacement of a normal dropdown box (at least in IE).

(I currently use a modified version of this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/AutoSuggestControl.aspx)

Comment: That probably is one of the possible solutions, but, unfortunately, replacing AJAX control Toolkit comboboxes isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure what "not possible" really means.  Do you realize that you could simply treat them each as a TextBox from ASP, send the list content as script, then do the rest in javascript?